# add booking date to woocomerce e-mail template

Tags: php, email, woocommerce

How to add "booking end date" to "woocomerce" email template?
I know that "woocommerce booking" has it own e-mail template, but because of specification of my project, I'm have to use only "woocomerce" template as an active e-mails template.
woocommerce e-mail

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be a bit more specific. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to modify function do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
 in customer-processing-order.php file (woocommerce file)

but I didn't find where I can modify content of variable $order

Comment: Have you found solution to this?